# Serve image in node.js fetched from another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, rendering

I feel like this should be simple enough, but I am having trouble making this work. I have a URL that the front-end hits. This triggers node to fetch an image from another server. Next I want node to send the image as the response. This part is not working for me.

```
render: function(img,response){
    request.get(URL, function (error, res, body) {
        if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
            response.writeHead(200);
            response.write(body);
            response.end();
        }
    });
}
```

Should I be buffering the image instead?

FYI I am trying to do this this way because the image i need to retrieve as authentication credentials in the src path, and I don't want those exposed to the user. So if you think that there is a better solution than what I am trying, please feel free to suggest. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine, but you've left out one important part, writing the data back to the response :)

You just need to add:

```
response.write(body); 
response.end();
```

After writing the headers.

Comment: Thanks aqidanok! I tried adding that (I had it in there before and had forgotten I had removed it briefly), but it's still not working. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Not sure tbh, I'd use curl or similar tool to examine the responses outside the browser and see what is going on.

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for an answer and the above did not work for you, try the request module like this.

First include the module

```
var request = require('request')
```

then:

```
request.get(URL, {encoding:'binary'},function(error, response){
             res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' });
             res.end(response.body, 'binary');
        });
```

This will bypass the image from the URL and print it into the response.